# Iteration over javascript objects

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

Write a function that takes Season number and episode number as input
and gives all the information about that particular episode as output

After taking inputs from the user as season number and episode number, it doesn't give output as the information about that particular episode

```
let BigBang =  { 
    "_embedded": {
        "episodes": [
          {
            "id": 2913,
            "name": "Pilot",
            "season": 1,
            "number": 1,
            "airdate": "2007-09-24",
            "airtime": "20:30",
            "airstamp": "2007-09-25T00:30:00+00:00",
            "runtime": 30,


            "_links": {
              "self": {
                "href": "http:\/\/api.tvmaze.com\/episodes\/2913"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "id": 2914,
            "name": "The Big Bran Hypothesis",
            "season": 1,
            "number": 2,
            "airdate": "2007-10-01",
            "airtime": "20:30",
            "airstamp": "2007-10-02T00:30:00+00:00",
            "runtime": 30,
            "image": {
              "medium": "http:\/\/static.tvmaze.com\/uploads\/images\/medium_landscape\/4\/12369.jpg",
              "original": "http:\/\/static.tvmaze.com\/uploads\/images\/original_untouched\/4\/12369.jpg"
            },
       }



    let season = prompt('Enter Season number');                               
    let number = prompt('Enter Episode number');                            
    let AllInfo = (season,number) => {                                   
        for(let current in BigBang._embedded.episodes) {                    
            if(BigBang._embedded.episodes[current].season === season) {                                              
                if(BigBang._embedded.episodes[current].number === number) { 
                let Detail = BigBang._embedded.episodes[current];
                    alert(Detail);
                }
            }
        }                            
    AllInfo(season,number);                         
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: It;s in the code above. scroll down you will see

Comment: Sorry I missed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.find` instead, it'll make the code a lot cleaner:

```js
    let BigBang = {
      "_embedded": {
        "episodes": [{
            "id": 2913,
            "name": "Pilot",
            "season": 1,
            "number": 1,
            "airdate": "2007-09-24",
            "airtime": "20:30",
            "airstamp": "2007-09-25T00:30:00+00:00",
            "runtime": 30,
            "_links": {
              "self": {
                "href": "http:\/\/api.tvmaze.com\/episodes\/2913"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "id": 2914,
            "name": "The Big Bran Hypothesis",
            "season": 1,
            "number": 2,
            "airdate": "2007-10-01",
            "airtime": "20:30",
            "airstamp": "2007-10-02T00:30:00+00:00",
            "runtime": 30,
            "image": {
              "medium": "http:\/\/static.tvmaze.com\/uploads\/images\/medium_landscape\/4\/12369.jpg",
              "original": "http:\/\/static.tvmaze.com\/uploads\/images\/original_untouched\/4\/12369.jpg"
            },
          }
        ]
      }
    }
    //const inputSeason = prompt('Enter Season number');
    const inputSeason = 1;
    //const inputNumber = prompt('Enter Episode number');
    const inputNumber = 2;

    const foundEpisode = BigBang._embedded.episodes.find(({ season, number}) => {
      return season === inputSeason && number === inputNumber;
    });
    if (foundEpisode) console.log(foundEpisode);
    else console.log('No matching season/number found!');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that easier with the find() method on your array.

```
let episode = BigBang._embedded.episodes.find((e) => {
    return e.season === season && e.number === number;
});
if (episode) {
    alert(episode.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have debugged your code and saw that you call **AllInfo** function within **AllInfo** .So there is recursive call happen in your code. So remove calling of **AllInfo** from AllInfo function, your issue will be fixed. Try the following code.

```
let BigBang =  { 
"_embedded": {
    "episodes": [
      {
        "id": 2913,
        "name": "Pilot",
        "season": 1,
        "number": 1,
        "airdate": "2007-09-24",
        "airtime": "20:30",
        "airstamp": "2007-09-25T00:30:00+00:00",
        "runtime": 30,


        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http:\/\/api.tvmaze.com\/episodes\/2913"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2914,
        "name": "The Big Bran Hypothesis",
        "season": 1,
        "number": 2,
        "airdate": "2007-10-01",
        "airtime": "20:30",
        "airstamp": "2007-10-02T00:30:00+00:00",
        "runtime": 30,
        "image": {
          "medium": "http:\/\/static.tvmaze.com\/uploads\/images\/medium_landscape\/4\/12369.jpg",
          "original": "http:\/\/static.tvmaze.com\/uploads\/images\/original_untouched\/4\/12369.jpg"
        },
   }]}};



let season = 1;                               
let number = 2;                            
let AllInfo = (season,number) => {                              
    for(let current in BigBang._embedded.episodes) {                    
        if(BigBang._embedded.episodes[current].season === season) {                                              
            if(BigBang._embedded.episodes[current].number === number) { 
            let Detail = BigBang._embedded.episodes[current];
                alert(JSON.stringify(Detail,null,4));
            }
        }
    }                                                     
}
AllInfo(season,number);
```